# What is the connection between the notions of cyclic permutation and cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

I am working with the following definitions:

> If a permutation consists of exactly one cycle (that is, if the $m$ for which $\pi^m = id_X$ is equal to the cardinality of $X$, $m = n$) then we say that $\pi$ is a **cyclic permutation**.

In the definition above, $X = \left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$.

> If a group $G$ has an element $a$ such that $G = \{ a^1, a^2,\ldots \}$ then we say that $G$ is a **cyclic group** and $a$ is the **generator** of $G$.

The name in the first definition is obviously very suggestive, but I'm not sure I can convince myself if the suggestion means anything. The existence of a cyclic permutation does not suggest that the symmetric group of order $n$, $S_n$, is cyclic. Thus my question is, **what, if any, is the connection between these two notions?**

To be clear, I am well aware that every element of a group generates its own cyclic subgroup, but this fact doesn't seem relevant to the naming convention here.

Comment: But the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by a cyclic permutation is indeed cyclic. Here "cyclic" is just an adjective. A cyclic permutation is not a cyclic group. Similarly, an abelian group is not directly related to an abelian variety.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But non-cyclic permutations also generate cyclic subgroups?

Comment: Indeed! This is what I want to say, "cyclic" is just an adjective. Its meaning depends on the noun.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see. So, to be sure, you say that there is no deep connection between the uses of cyclic in the two cases? If so, I'd be happy to accept any answer which you supply to that effect !

Comment: There are cycle graphs, cyclic groups, cyclic permutations, cyclic codes, cyclic extensions, cyclic polygons, cyclic homology, cyclic numbers  etc. in mathematics. The only "deep connection" is the word cyclic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Fair enough. I guess I imagined some connection insofar as both are standard definitions introduced early in any development of group theory. The others are, at least to me, a little more arcane :)

Comment: The word "cyclic" just means "circle-like".  A cyclic permutation permutes $1\mapsto2 \mapsto3\dots \mapsto n\mapsto1$ in a circle. A cyclic group has a similar structure: it can be thought of as the symmetry of a circle with $n$ dots spaced evenly around the perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about the connection between a cyclic permutation and a cyclic group. [Cayley's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)
states that every group is isomorphic to a subgroup
of the symmetric group using the regular representation.
Thus, in the regular representation of a cyclic group
the generator maps into a cyclic permutation of the
elements of the group. Of course, you can add
extra elements to the permutated set which are
fixed by the permutation.

Conversely, given a cyclic permutation. say
$\, \pi = (a_1 a_2 ... a_n) ,\,$ the permuted set
$\, \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}\,$ can be given a
cyclic group structure where $a_1$ is the
identity element and $a_2$ is a generator.
Multiplication of $a_i$ and $a_j$ is equal
to $a_k$ where $i+j \equiv k+1\pmod n.\,$
The permutation $\pi$ corresponds to the
generator $a_2$.